# virtual destructors vs normal destructor

Tags: c++

Just a simple question.

the compiler gives me the option : virtual destructor, but I create a normal class without the virtual destructor

Is adding the word `virtual` before `~` the same as creating the class with a virtual destructor made by the compiler?

example

before:

```
~String();
```

after:

```
virtual ~String();
```

I am asking this question because I use other classes pointers inside of my "parent" class.

Comment: Did you mean IDE instead of compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use virtual destructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 0):

> *Is adding the word virtual before ~ the same as creating the class with a virtual destructor made by the compiler?*

No, it is not the same thing. Virtual destructors are useful when you have a parent and child class, and you want to delete an instance of the base class by first deleting the instance of the child class. This prevents a memory leak, which would have otherwise happenened if your destructor was not virtual; the base class instance would only have been deleted, leaving the derived instance to cause a memory leak.

See this example:

```
Parent *object = new Child();

// Do stuff

delete object;
```

If the child class destructor is virtual, then the memory alloted for the `Child` instance will be cleared first, and then the `Parent` instance will be cleared, ensuring that no memory leak take place.

If the `Child` destructor is **not** virtual, then the `Parent` instance will only be deleted, because `object` is an instance of `Parent*`. The `Child` instance will not be deleted, thus causing a memory leak.

Understanding the definition of ***virtual*** may be of use here:

> *...what the virtual keyword does is to allow a member of a derived class with the same name as one in the base class to be appropriately called from a pointer, and more precisely when the type of the pointer is a pointer to the base class that is pointing to an object of the derived class...*

Sources:

- [Polymorphism: C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)
- [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)